# The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions

Tags: security, odoo

I have created new add-on as like as survey add-on. Module consist 3 level of groups,

1. Head Manager(admin)
2. Manager
3. User

If i am logged in as a manager and print the report, i am getting below warning,

```
"AccessError: ('AccessError', u'The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions.
Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: res.partner, Operation: read)') "
```

My rules are:

### Manager:

```
<record model="res.groups" id="base.group_survey_manager">
<field name="name">Custom Survey  Manager</field>
<field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_survey_user'))]"/>
<field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

---

```
<record id="project_survey_manager_access" model="ir.rule">
<field name="name">Survey Manager access rights</field>
<field name="model_id" ref="custom_survey.model_custom_project_survey"/>
<field name="domain_force">[(1, '=', 1)]</field>
<field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_survey_manager'))]"/>
<field eval="1" name="perm_unlink"/>
<field eval="1" name="perm_write"/>
<field eval="1" name="perm_read"/>
<field eval="1" name="perm_create"/>
</record>
```

### Partner Form Security:

```
<record id="partner_list_access" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Access to the manager to list related partners</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[('create_uid', '=', user.id)]</field>            
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_survey_manager'))]"/>
    </record>
```

If the manager is logged-in, i would like to list the partner who is created by the current manager. That's why i added the partner rule.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Access to the manager to list related partners
        
        [('create_uid','=',user.id)]

Here, there is no meaning to apply security access for create remove it, add simple domain to filter records.

If you want to restrict user to create then give that rights into the access rights csv file.

Comment: I have modified the code in "Partner Form Security". Still same issue. Please check once. If i am unchecked the "Apply to read" check box from rules, my report is printing properly without warning. But listing all partners.

Comment: It's because there is parent/child relation in res.partner, and it's not advisable to use read rule to partner object, generally each user can have read access to partner because there are many places in ERP where you can see partner field like invoice, sale order etc. then you will see many issues while dealing with them.

Comment: Even though you want to apply rule to partner then you have to do something like this,
['|','|',('parent_id','=',False),('parent_id','=',user.parent_id.id),('create_uid','=',user.id)].

Answer (score 0):

Goto Settings -> Manage Access Rights -> select the user -> check the option of PORTAL in 'other extra rights' at the bottom. if it is black so mark it True.